# Locating a common global value in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, global-variables

I have a global variable `UNLIMITED` which I want to have the value of `-9` and to be set once for all the models instead of in each model separately. Where can I define it?

On a more general note, common things for views are usually in the layout, commons for the controllers are in the `application_controller.rb`, where do the commons for models should be located? I tried putting in `application.rb`, no success.

Comment: Put it in an initializer

Comment: @RSB under what name? at which format? which file name? 

could you please provide an example?

Comment: Check my answer, it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an initializer file named `constants.rb` in `/config/initializers/` directory, in that file add

```
#This file contains global constants
UNLIMITED = -9 #Explanation of why unlimited is -9
```

Save the file and then restart the server, now you can use that constant anywhere in your application

Comment: FOA Thanks!

What about common methods? let's say I want to create a method named `my_name` which will return the value of `model_name.plural` for each model (e.g. for `User` model it'll return `User.model_name.plural`, so on for each model). in a `/lib` module?

Comment: You can use `pluralize` for that, try `User.model_name.pluralize`

Comment: clear, but I meant something else: DRYing the code such that I write something like

`def my_name (\n)

 self.model_name.plural  (\n)

end`

where do I put such method, so each model/controller would be able to access it and use it properly?

Comment: I guess then you need to add it in ActiveRecord::Base class

Comment: and if I prefer avoiding all of those monkey-patches, any other way?